# C++, how to make the console application work in the background after it is closed?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, process, background

Is there any way to do this? I mean, close the console application but not the process, the app still works in the background.
I'm on Windows

Comment: Is there a reason this has to be a console application? The normal way to make a background application would be to not have a console in the first place.

Comment: When your application starts, it would need to spawn a non-console background server that does all of the work that's unrelated to the user interface. The foreground console UI process cannot avoid termination when the console is closed. It is too late to call `FreeConsole`. Once the application receives the console `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`, it has 5 seconds to exit gracefully on its own, after which the Windows session server (csrss.exe) forcefully terminates it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of ways of doing this:

1. You can just hide the console by doing something like `ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);` or `FreeConsole(void);`
2. Use `int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow);` and set the last parameter to false (if you're using windows)

But to have away of when you close the window and have it still run, I'm not entirely sure. Best way would be to have some command to just hide the window.

Comment: Only hide the console window if `GetWindowThreadProcessId` considers your process to be the effective owner of the window. For normal console windows, conhost.exe is the real owner of the window, but the system keeps track of an effective owner. Usually it's the client process that allocated the console session. Note that with a ConPTY session in Windows 10, such as under Windows Terminal, conhost.exe (or openconsole.exe) owns the window that's returned by `GetConsoleWindow`, which is just a hidden window that exists to satisfy the API.